# Running cURL Commands as VSTS Build Task

Tags: curl, azure-devops

I need to incorporate into my VSTS build definition, a Task that executes a number of cURL commands  which I'm able to run successfully in Postman.

Essentially, I have a number of cURL commands which perform following respective tasks:

1. Login to an application database through a randomly generated access token.
2. Obtain a list of solution IDs held in the database.
3. From a selected solution ID, retrieve a list of stored files.

I am not going to list the entire set of Tasks for sake of brevity, but I believe the above provides a good illustration on what this requirement is about.

Using the above three scenarios only, what I would therefore like to set up are three cURL commands which can be transformed into three individual VSTS build definition Tasks, using cURL as the language type, or any other scripting language that will be supported in VSTS.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

You can use one of the following tasks to do it:

**cURL task**

This one is used to upload files with a cURL

[image]

**Run script - a command line**

Just pass the cURL command and the arguments

[image]

**Powershell script**

You can call cURL directly from powershell.

[image]

To do all your tasks you could add one task (item) for each one of them, or using powershell add all into one powershell file and then execute it.

Comment: Hello Rodrigo, thank you ever so much for this. This is precisely what I needed and will give it a go. Would you happen to have some actual examples too please?

Comment: @hitman126 You just need to call curl command in PowerShell or Command Line task. What's the problem you do it?

Comment: But is it essential at all to include the preceding "Upload with cURL" Task, as I have no intention of uploading any objects as far as my requirement is concerned?

Comment: No need to include upload with cURL. You can just call it in a PowerShell or command line task. I recommend you to take a look at Microsoft documentation on how to do it

Comment: Batch script task and bash task are also able to call cURL.